# How to save files using Javascript / JQuery where the 'website' is all local

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a system that was built in JavaScript for a website ages ago which I need to make slight changes for; which includes saving the data to be loaded again later.

The main difference is this time the system will be completely local; no server whatsoever.

What is the best way to save/update (& load) a file in locally; ideally without a download prompt.

Comment: You can't, with the exception of using Chrome's own Filesystem API that uses a sandboxed area to save files

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `[localStorage][1]`.

What you can do with localStorage is retrieve the image as Base64 in localStorage and then when page is loaded you can access to localStorageto get the image and put in your img tag.

Here's is working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/joherro3/Gg6AG/506/